# Using Intent for taking photo and edit preview

Tags: android, camera, photo, preview

I'm taking photo using following code:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setImageBitmap(photo);    
        }
}
```

I want to edit Preview before delivering to my app. 
After taking photo a dialog shown that user must confirm photo. I want to edit image on this preview.

**Update :**

**in fact I want to add a watermark to photo. When user click capture button, he must see an image with watermark and not original image!**

Is it possible or I must use Camera API instead of Intent?

Comment: What are you trying to edit on the picture? I would simply ask the user if he wants to edit the picture after taking it and then send this to another view, process the image doing w-e you need, then continue with the app like it used to be. Hope this can help a bit

Comment: I want to add a watermark to photo. When user click capture button, he must see an image with watermark and not original image! could you give me a sample code?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to edit Preview before delivering to my app.

There is no requirement that an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity have any means to allow you to force the user to edit the image before it is returned to you in `onActivityResult()`.

> After taking photo a dialog shown that user must confirm photo.

There is no requirement that an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity have any means to allow you to force the user to confirm the image before it is returned to you in `onActivityResult()`.

The implementation of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activities is up to the developers of those activities, not you.

> or I must use Camera API instead of Intent ?!

Using a native camera API will not help you, as the native camera API does not offer an image editor. If you want the user to edit an image, you will need to either try `ACTION_EDIT` on the image (which may or may not be supported on any given device) or add an image editor to your app.

Comment: I want to add a watermark to photo. When user click capture button, he must see an image with watermark and not raw image.

Comment: @Jessica: You are welcome to add a watermark to the image once the image is delivered to your app and show the modified image to the user. Everything prior to that is handled by the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity, and you have no means of forcing one of those to blend in your watermark.